# Sharepoint 2013 doesn't render link to my file specified via JSLink on a LVWP

Tags: 2013, jslink

I've done the following:

1. List item
2. Created an OOTB SharePoint 2013 site
3. Uploaded some javascript to _catalogs/masterpage (as a JavaScript Display Template)
4. Published the javascript file.
5. Created a new page
6. Added a list view webpart to the page, and set the JSLink to refer to the JS file in #2 (I've tried absolute references, plus ~site and ~sitecollection-prefixed references).
7. Published the page.

While I understand my template may not be perfect (and hence I put a 'debugger;' line near the beginning of the anonymous function), I'm expecting SharePoint to at least render a link to it when I visit the page, but I see no indication that my code is running, and in the source of the page, I see no reference to my javascript file (nor inlined content from it).  I also don't see anything about my file or JSLink in ULS logs for rendering that page.

What's my next debugging step?  Is there some feature I need to make sure is enabled so I can use the JSLink property?  Does JSLink not work with some kinds of lists?  Are there some settings on the LVWP that are incompatible with JSLink?  Could I be missing a farm/webapp feature?

All the examples I can find assume that SharePoint renders that link, making me think I'm doing something incredibly stupid and simple that's breaking this.

Answer (score 1):

This is digging up old things to reply on, but:

- Make sure server render is not on.
- Make sure you can reach the js file by typing the address into the address bar.
- Make sure you use google chrome in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem. I finally determined that the issue was that my .js file that I uploaded had underscores in the file name. so I would try again with the filename having no underscores. [jslink file cannot have underscores](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128991/jslink-file-cannot-have-underscores)